# Are these pronouns semantic subjects of to-infinitives?

Tags: complementation

> (1)
>  Hermione opened her mouth, perhaps to tell Ron exactly how to
>   use the Curse of the Bogies, but Harry hissed at **her** to be quiet
>   and beckoned them all forward. 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)
>
> (2)
>  Harry waved madly at **the other three** to follow him as
>   quickly as possible.
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Do we say that the highlighted parts are the semantic subjects of to-infinitives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Harry hissed at her to be quiet.
>   Harry waved madly at the other three to follow him.

*Her* and *the other three* are the semantic Agents of the following infinitives; but I whether they are the grammatical subjects of those infinitives is tricky. What is clearly **not** the case is this parsing:

> <sup>✲</sup> [<sub>SUBJECT</sub> Harry ] [<sub>VERB</sub> hissed at ] [<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub> she *BE* quiet ]
>   <sup>✲</sup> [<sub>SUBJECT</sub> Harry ] [<sub>VERB</sub> waved at ] [<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub> they *FOLLOW* him ]

That makes no sense. I think rather what we have here are the verbs *HISS* and *WAVE* employed bitransitively, taking two complements—an indirect object<sup>†</sup> representing the person to whom a communication is addressed and a direct object representing the content of the communication. I thus see these sentences as having this structure:

> [<sub>SUBJECT</sub> Harry ] [<sub>VERB</sub> hissed ] [<sub>COMPL-IndObj</sub> at her  ] [<sub>COMPL-DirObj</sub> she *BE* quiet ]
>   [<sub>SUBJECT</sub> Harry ] [<sub>VERB</sub> waved ] [<sub>COMPL-IndObj</sub> at them ] [<sub>COMPL-DirObj</sub> they *FOLLOW* him ]

The final DirObj complement is realized as an infinitival subordinate clause (*<strike>she</strike> to be quiet*, *<strike>they</strike> to follow him*) whose subject is deleted because it is the same as the preceding indirect object of the main clause. This is the ‘Equi’ process which Prof. Lawler describes in pellucid detail [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

So the actual subjects of these infinitives have been deleted; but the indirect objects which are left indicate what they would be if they were still there.

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable*
<sup>†</sup> This will trouble traditional grammarians: the radicals declare that the object of a preposition cannot be an indirect object, while the merely conservative declare that an indirect object must be introduced by *to* or *for*. I ground my analysis in analogies like these:*

[image]

It's entirely natural for verbs like *hiss*, *wave*, *bark*, *growl* which have common monotransitive uses with *at* to carry that preposition over into bitransitive uses.

Comment: When a preposition followed, they are likely to call the indirect object differently: McCawley -> to-dative (The Syntactic Phenomena of English, ch.4; Angela Downing, English Grammar, 11.2 Say and Tell -> oblique object)

Comment: @Listenever That's very handy, thank you; henceforward I shall call these ***at*-datives** !

Comment: I guess, "prepositional object" [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar) is a lot more  understandable for me.

Answer (score 0):

*The other three* is part of the prepositional phrase *at the other three*; it is not the subject of the infinitive, which is used to show purpose of intention.

> To open the door, push the button.

*To follow him as quickly as possible* describes the reason why Harry waved madly. It was not to greet them, but to make them follow him.

Comment: Not so fast! The infinitives do not express **Harry's** purpose: that is for *her* and *the other three* to perform the actions which the infinitives express. *Hissed* and *waved* here are bi-transitive here, like *say*, but employing *at* rather than *to* to designate their indirect objects; and the indirect objects are the agents/subjects of the following infinitives. Check out [John Lawler's discussion](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: The example as given here can only be parsed one way, which interpretation is still available if it's re-sequenced as *Push the button to open the door*. But the resequenced version can also be parsed as *Push the button **whose function is** to open the door* (as opposed to pushing the button that dims the lights, say).

Comment: @StoneyB, A sentence in professor John Lawer’s article, ‘I listened to him tell the story once again’, it seems like we have to say ‘[listened][to him tell the story]’(transitive verb ‘listened’ and its object. But Oxford possibly has different thought [link](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/listen) : intransitive ‘listen’ and preposition ‘to’ together come to a transitive group. Is this old, and the previous new?

Comment: @Listenever Prof. Lawler's analysis doesn't take account of this collocation, because it isn't really affected either way (note that he says the verb is ***listen** (to)*). I'd be a little more comfortable with treating the verb as transitive *listen to* = *hear*.

Comment: @StoneyB I can see that Oxford has the same opinion as you: hiss and wave are di-transitive verbs. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Listenever It is di-transive in "I waved her goodbye."